# Secure Store Target Application (Group) Setting credential owners to Everyone gives Access Denied error

Tags: external-content-type, secure-store

I'm using an external content type in Sharepoint 2013. As part of setting it up, I have setup a Secure Store Application ID. While setting up a secure store application ID, I've set it to Type = Group, Credential Owners = Everyone. Then I've specified the Windows Username and Password that I want to be used to access my SQL Server.

I've already tested that this user name and password can access the database by Running SQL Server Management Studio as a different user and using the above username and password. The view that I select on returns all the records. So I know that my user is setup correctly on SQL Server.

However, when I go to Sharepoint and launch the picker control to pick values from the External Content Type, I'm getting this error.

'Access denied. You do not have permission to access this content.'

Any ideas what I'm perhaps doing wrong? I'm relatively new to using External Content Types.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is Business Data Connectivity permissions in the Central Administration.

Central Administration -> Application Management -> Manage Service Applications -> Business Data Connectivity. Select the content type and then click on the Set Object Permissions button. Add any users that will need access to this content type. (Doh! Always easy once you find out the root cause).